# Delegate reference itself

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there a way for a delegate to reference itself? I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
delegate void Foo();
list<Foo> foos;

void test() {
    list.Add(delegate() {
        list.Remove(/* this delegate */);
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with such a construct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?  Do you just want to remove the delegate from your `foos` list?

Comment: This is a simplified example of what I need to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it's possible for a delegate to reference itself like this:

```
delegate void Foo();
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

void test() {
    Foo del = null;
    del = delegate { foos.Remove(del); };

    foos.Add(del);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is for the delegate to accept an argument for itself:

```
delegate void Foo(Foo self);
...
list.Add(delegate (Foo self) { list.Remove(self);});
...
foreach (Foo f in list) f(f);
```

Another way would be to close over a variable refering to itself:

```
Foo foo;
foo = delegate() { list.Remove(foo);}
list.Add(foo);
```